# User defined explicit conversion in conditionals in C++11

Tags: c++11, type-conversion

I define a user-defined conversion operator to `bool` and use it in a conditional:

```
struct T {
  explicit operator bool() { return true; }
};

int main() {
   T t;
   return t ? 0 : 1;
}
```

To my surprise this compiles (on gcc) despite the `explicit`.  Is this allowed by the C++11 standard? I searched the standard but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first operand to the conditional operator is *contextually converted* to `bool` (`[expr.cond]/1`). This is defined as follows (quote from N3337):

> `[conv]/3:` An expression `e` appearing in such a context is said to be *contextually converted to `bool`* and is well-formed if and only if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed, for some
>   invented temporary variable `t`.

So contextual conversion uses direct-initialization rules, which allow for `explicit` user-defined conversions.